# What is the Correct LifeCycleEventArgs to use in Symfony 2.5 preUpdate Event Listener

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

In a Symfony 2.5 `preUpdate` event listener, I'm confused about whether/when to pass in `LifeCycleEventArgs` or `PreUpdateEventArgs` (and which one).

The [Doctrine Documentation](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/events.html#lifecycle-callbacks-event-argument) says that starting in 2.4 you use `LifeCycleEventArgs`:

> Since 2.4 the triggered event is given to the lifecycle-callback. With
>   the additional argument you have access to the EntityManager and
>   UnitOfWork APIs inside these callback methods.

But the example directly below that and all subsequent examples show `PreUpdateEventArgs`:

```
class User
{
    public function preUpdate(PreUpdateEventArgs $event)
    {
        if ($event->hasChangedField('username')) {
            // Do something when the username is changed.
        }
    }
}
```

So does that mean `LifeCycleEventArgs` (if it's available in your version) will do all that `PreUpdateEventArgs` does and more? They both seem to work (i.e. no errors).

And using the new LifeCycleEventArgs, is it still necessary to use `$entity->setNewValue('fieldName', $value)`? Is preUpdate still as restrictive or can we just do `$entity->setFieldName($value)`?

Answer (score 3):

On Doctrine 2.2, `class PreUpdateEventArgs extends LifecycleEventArgs` and it only declares the entity changeset for the entity being pre-updated.
So yes, `PreUpdateEventArgs` does more, though theoretically (i.e. I didn't test that!) you could achieve the same using the EM's UOW:

1. In the `LifecycleEventArgs`, you can access the entity that has triggered the event using `getEntity()`.
2. Same class, you can access the EM using `getEntityManager()`
3. Hence: `$this->getEntityManager()->getUnitOfWork()->getEntityChangeSet($this->getEntity())` should give you the same changeset as the one provided by `PreUpdateEventArgs`

Conclusion: `PreUpdateEventArgs` facilitates a job that could already be achieved using slightly more code ;)

To dive a little deeper: `UnitOfWork::commit()` triggers the update by calling `UnitOfWork::executeUpdates`, which dispatches an instance of `PreUpdateEventArgs` filled with the already-computed changeset for this entity, directly taken from the UOW's changesets. (Again: I'm using 2.2, might be different on your release.)

About the `$event->setNewValue('field', 'value')` vs. `$entity->setField('value')`, I believe you need to just update the changeset (which is `setNewValue`'s job). Calling the entity's setter directly might de-synchronize the entity from its state in DB or, more probably, just be useless as it shouldn't be taken into consideration. Except if you manually call the UOW's `computeChangeSets()`.

Hope this helps!